# Must I reset a variable to null in each iteration in a Postgres plpgsql procedure?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I have this simple postgres procedure (example) in plpgsql language.
Must I do a "_current_id = null" before calling the select into ? or _current_id always will be null when select not found any matching row?. I know I can test, but I don't want to suffer in future for a bad practice. But also don't want to add an innecesary extra line of code

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE
     _current_id integer;
     _row record;
    BEGIN
     FOR _row IN select * from my_table LOOP
        select id into _current_id from my_second_table where name=row.name;
         if (_current_id is null) then
           --my code here
         end if;
     END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: No, you don't need to do that. But why the separate SELECT statement inside the loop? You could do this much more efficiently with a single statement: `for _row in select st.id from my_second_table st where st.name in (select mt.name from my_table) loop ...`

Comment: Because in each iteration I need to check if row exists in the second table, if not, insert and get the id of the inserted record and then insert in another table (3rd) referencing this new id.

Comment: That could be done more efficiently with a single INSERT statement

Comment: yes , you could do it in one insert statement , seems like you don't need to loop

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: maybe merge your comments into an answer to close this one?